# iOS. Background modes and network checking

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, voip, pushkit, background-mode

I need to implement such feature:

every time than app get internet connection I need to send request to web server. I need to do it from Background than app is not launched. So, what Background mode should I use for that and how to implement that feature?

Comment: You can use background fetch, but it check "every time there is an internet connection", it will just check periodically, controlled by iOS

Comment: @Paulw11, can I use VOIP for that?

Comment: No, use of background fetch doesn't require any VoIP features.

Comment: @Paulw11, well are there any other ways to stay always in the background and check network manually?

Comment: Do you want AppStore approval?  You can keep,a socket alive in the background if you are a VoIP app, but this isn't recommended. The use of Pushkit is the preferred approach for VoIP apps. Polling is bad for battery and network usage. Push is a better approach